# Having a keyboard language not appear when switching using keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, language

I'm using Windows 10 and have two languages (English, Hebrew) which I use all the time, so I'm using the **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>** keyboard shortcut to switch between one and the other.

I lately started studying Spanish, so I also wanted to have that installed for when I do my homework, but now I have to switch between three languages all the time, only so I can have Spanish installed once a week when I need it.

Is there a way to have Spanish installed so I can only switch to it manually and not using the keyboard shortcut?  The shortcut will then only switch between English and Hebrew?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the Windows dialog is impossible, but you can set shortcut keys
for each language, to go directly and quickly to the language you need:

- Go to *Settings > Devices > Typing*
- Click *Advanced keyboard settings*
- Click *Input language hot keys*
- Click on a keyboard layout to select
- Click *Change Key Sequence…*
- Click *Enable Key Sequence*
- Choose your shortcut and click OK

[image]